# sound plays automatically - flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

On one frame in my flash project there are 6 buttons.  When you click a button a different song plays.  Simple.  The problem is, the first song in the list is playing the second the project loads instead of waiting for someone to click the button!

```
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
var snd:Sound;
var channel:SoundChannel;
var trans:SoundTransform;
var currSong:String;
var currVol:Number = .5;
var currPan:Number = 0;


var songList:Array=new Array("Drifting.mp3","Push.mp3",
                             "Stupid.mp3","Train Wreck.mp3","World on Fire.mp3","Fallen.mp3");


panSlide.visible=false;
volSlide.visible=false;


song1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
panSlide.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, panChange);
volSlide.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, volumeChange);



function chooseSong(e:MouseEvent):void {
    switch (e.currentTarget.name) {
        case "song1":
            currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[0] as String;
            break;

        case "song2":
            currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[1] as String;
            break;

        case "song3":
            currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[2] as String;
            break;

        case "song4":
            currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[3] as String;
            break;

        case "song5":
            currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[4] as String;
            break;

        case "song6":
            currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[5] as String;
            break;
    }
    if (snd != null) {
        channel.stop();
    }
    snd = new Sound();
    snd.load(new URLRequest(currSong));

    channel = new SoundChannel  ;
    trans = new SoundTransform(currVol,currPan);
    channel = snd.play();
    channel.soundTransform = trans;
    panSlide.visible = true;
    volSlide.visible = true;
}


function volumeChange(e:SliderEvent):void {
    currVol = e.target.value;
    trans.volume = currVol;
    channel.soundTransform = trans;
}



function panChange(e:SliderEvent):void {
    currPan = e.target.value;
    trans.pan = e.target.value;
    channel.soundTransform = trans;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you haven´t accidentally added a sound to the timeline? If not you should add a trace inside the method chooseSong and check if it is triggered when you load the project.

I created a new file with a mc (song1) on stage and this script. Does this work for you?

```
song1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);

function chooseSong(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace (e.currentTarget.name)
}
```

Comment: well what do you know, I did add it tot he time line.  Removed that but now nothing at all plays when you click the buttons.

Comment: Do you get the correct sound url in the function? trace(currSong) after the switch.

Comment: I dont get anything - and adding trace(currSong) doesnt do anything either, nothing happens when you press the buttons period.

Comment: What is "song1"? Is it a Movieclip?

Comment: Sound like you are not getting the listener to work at all. Updated my answer.

Comment: You might need to select "Export for Actionscript" in the properties of your movieclips.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a shot in the dark, but you didn't happen to accidentally add the song to the stage somewhere? That may or may not cause the song to play automatically when the movie loads.

Check your controls as well, a simple mis-click could be the issue.